# Omitting preposition in clock time expressions

Tags: prepositions, time

Googling for a time expression with and without ‘at’:

- *“Leaves at 8am”* yields ~ 24k hits
- *“Leaves 8am”* yields ~ 4k

Is omitting the ‘at’ preposition here a less formal register, just an alternative form or outright ungrammatical?

Answer (score 2):

Whether you say *leaves 8 am* or *leaves at 8 am* is less a matter of register as text genre. Information in a list, on a calendar, or some other kind of schedule will often be written in a highly economical style, in an earlier time called *[telegram style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_style)*, in which only the most pertinent information is given and anything excess is removed.

So, for instance, information about a bus from Fresno to Yellowstone National Park:

> [BUS 2](https://sierranewsonline.com/ride-yarts-free-to-yosemite-on-earth-day/)
>
> LEAVES 8:30 AM FROM FRESNO AMTRAK/GREYHOUND
>
> LEAVES 10 AM FROM OAKHURST BEST WESTERN
>
> ARRIVES YOSEMITE VALLEY VISITOR CENTER 11:30 AM
>
> LEAVES YOSEMITE VALLEY VISITOR CENTER AT 4:35 PM
>
> ARRIVES OAKHURST BEST WESTERN 6:05 PM
>
> ARRIVES FRESNO AMTRAK/GREYHOUND 7:35 PM

This even *looks* like a telegram, which was always in all caps. Notice that an *at* sneaks in, since that's the usual way people give a time of day in normal conversation.

Here is a description for a snorkling trip, first described in the usual adjective-laden style of tourist brochures, but switching to telegram style for the scheduling information at the end.

> [Guana Cay Adventure](http://www.abacoinfo.com/travel/activities/froggies.htm)
>
> Enjoy a fabulous day as we cruise thru the blue seas of Abaco on our way to Great Guana Cay where we'll stop and snorkel at the breathtaking high rocks reef. Afterwards we'll explore the local settlement and have lunch and drinks at Nippers Bar and Grill. We'll then move on to the northernmost tip of Guana to walk the shores of one of the most breathtaking beaches in the world. *Leaves 10 AM, returns 4 PM. Lunch excluded, all gear provided. $45 per person*.

In other contexts, the tendency is toward including the preposition.